# Failed to setup php on nginx on mac ox

Tags: php, nginx

I tried to setup nginx to serve php web site on mac os. But when I open a php file from browser it shows a blank page without any error. I have installed php and nginx related application. Below is my php file:

```
<?php
 phpinfo(); 
?>
```

below is my nginx config file:

```
http{
        server{
                listen  8082;
                root /Users/joey/tmp;
        location / {
            index  index.html index.htm index.php;
        }
                location ~ \.php$ {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
                include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        autoindex on;
                }


        }
}
events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}
```

I have verifed that php-fpm has started and listening on port 9000:

```
$ lsof -Pni4 | grep LISTEN | grep php
php-fpm   43310 joey    6u  IPv4 0xdcff1b2732b9c88d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   43311 joey    0u  IPv4 0xdcff1b2732b9c88d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   43312 joey    0u  IPv4 0xdcff1b2732b9c88d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
php-fpm   43313 joey    0u  IPv4 0xdcff1b2732b9c88d      0t0  TCP 127.0.0.1:9000 (LISTEN)
```

below is my php and nginx version:

```
$ nginx -v
nginx version: nginx/1.10.2
$ php -version
PHP 5.6.29 (cli) (built: Dec  9 2016 07:03:56) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.6.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
```

Is there anything wrong with my configuration?

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I found I need below configuration on nginx.conf file to enable php request:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
                        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
                        fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
                    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                        fastcgi_index index.php;
                        include /usr/local/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
                        autoindex on;
                }
```